# Best way to create a dictionary that will contain every possibility of a given range of values and date?

Tags: python, loops

I wrote the following script to do the above mentioned.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def prv( name, arg ):
    print( f'\n{name} -> {type(arg)} -> {arg}' )

def pri( name, arg ):
    print( f'\n{name} -> {len(arg)} -> {arg}' )

def convert_str_to_pydate ( date, dateformat="%d/%m/%Y"):
    refdate = datetime.strptime( date, dateformat )
    return refdate

def main():
    start_date = convert_str_to_pydate( '1/03/2020' )
    last_date = convert_str_to_pydate( '5/03/2020' )
    period = (last_date - start_date).days + 1
    prv( 'period', period) 
    period_dates = [ start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range( period ) ]
    pri( 'period_dates', period_dates) 
    values = [ i for i in range(3,0,-1) ]
    pri( 'values', values) 

    count = 0
    for i in period_dates:
        for v1 in values:
            for v2 in values:
                b = { i:v1 for i in period_dates }
                b[i] = v2
                print( count, b )
                count += 1

main()
```

It returned the following:

```
period -> <class 'int'> -> 5

period_dates -> 5 -> [datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0)]

values -> 3 -> [3, 2, 1]
0 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
1 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
2 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
3 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
4 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
5 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
6 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
7 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
8 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
9 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
10 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
11 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
12 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
13 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
14 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
15 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
16 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
17 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
18 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
19 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
20 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
21 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
22 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
23 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
24 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
25 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
26 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
27 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
28 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
29 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
30 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
31 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
32 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
33 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
34 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
35 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
36 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
37 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
38 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 3, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
39 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
40 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
41 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 2, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
42 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 3}
43 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 2}
44 {datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 4, 0, 0): 1, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 5, 0, 0): 1}
```

However, there are these repeated outputs:

- loop 0 output is repeated 4 times at loop  9, 18, 27 and 36.
- loop 4 output is repeated 4 times at loop 13, 22, 31 and 40.
- loop 8 output is repeated 4 times at loop 17, 26, 35 and 44.

Questions:

1. How do I avoid these repeats without storing them in a set or list?
2. What is the best way to do this in python3?

Comment: See `itertools.product`.

Comment: So your expected output would be a list of dicts, or what exactly? What do you permute? The dates, the values to test? Your expected output doesn't make that clear. Please provide some clear and definite input and output, and clarify the way to obtain it.

Comment: Consider using [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and then make a dictionary via dictionary comprehension

Comment: @ThierryLathuille. I have revised my question.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I think `itertools.product` does do what I need. I will work on it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by @chepner, my script should be revised to:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import product

def prv( name, arg ):
    print( f'\n{name} -> {type(arg)} -> {arg}' )

def pri( name, arg ):
    print( f'\n{name} -> {len(arg)} -> {arg}' )

def convert_str_to_pydate ( date, dateformat="%d/%m/%Y"):
    refdate = datetime.strptime( date, dateformat )
    return refdate

def main():
    start_date = convert_str_to_pydate( '1/03/2020' )
    last_date = convert_str_to_pydate( '5/03/2020' )
    period = (last_date - start_date).days + 1
    prv( 'period', period) 
    period_dates = [ start_date + timedelta(days=x) for x in range( period ) ]
    pri( 'period_dates', period_dates) 
    values = [ i for i in range(3,0,-1) ]
    pri( 'values', values) 

    print('\nUsing itertools.product')
    for count, i in enumerate( product( values, repeat=len(period_dates) ) ):
        desired = i[::-1] # reverse the tuple i
        b = { x:desired[n] for n, x in enumerate( period_dates ) }
        print( count, b )
```